# Getting error in jquery hide and show function

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery and materializecss to design my login portal. I want to implement hide and show functionality on the login page when user clicks on sign up button login div will hide and sign up div will show but I am getting some error in it. I need help please. Here is my code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>  Login Portal </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/materializecss.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
  <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
         <script>
         new WOW().init();
         </script>
         <style>
          .btn-login{
            padding: 5px 5px 20px 5px !important;
          }
          .back-icon{
            padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
            z-index: 1;
          }
         </style>

         <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/materializecss.min.js"></script>
   </head>
  <body>
    <div class="back-icon">
      <a href="index.php" > <img src="images/back1.png"> </a>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
    <h3 class="center light-blue-text">  <img src="images/logo.png"> </h3>
    <div class="col s3">
    </div>
    <div class="col s6" id="login" >
      <form style="box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px 2px #ccc;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
          <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="icon_prefix">Email Id</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">vpn_key</i>
          <input id="icon_telephone" type="tel" class="validate">
          <label for="icon_telephone">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s12 center btn-login">
              <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light light-blue"  type="submit" name="action">Submit
                <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
              </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 input-field">
          <div class="col s4 left">
            <button id="forgetpassword-button"> Forget Passoword ? </button>
          </div>
          <div class="col s4">
          </div>
          <div class="col s2 right">
            <button id="signup-button"> Sign Up </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col s6" id="signup" style="display:none">
    <form style="box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px 2px #ccc;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
        <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
        <label for="icon_prefix">Email Id</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <i class="material-icons prefix">vpn_key</i>
        <input id="icon_telephone" type="tel" class="validate">
        <label for="icon_telephone">Password</label>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12 center btn-login">
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light light-blue" type="submit"  name="action">Submit
              <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col s12 input-field">
        <div class="col s4 left">
          <a href="" id="forgetpassword-button"> Forget Passoword ? </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col s4">
        </div>
        <div class="col s2 right">
          <a href="" id="login-button"> Sign In </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="col s6" id="forgetpassword"  style="display:none">
  <form style="box-shadow: 1px 2px 6px 2px #ccc;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
      <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
      <label for="icon_prefix">Email Id</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <i class="material-icons prefix">vpn_key</i>
      <input id="icon_telephone" type="tel" class="validate">
      <label for="icon_telephone">Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s12 center btn-login">
          <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light light-blue"  type="submit" name="action">Submit
            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
          </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 input-field">
      <div class="col s4 left">
        <a href="" id="login-button"> Sign In </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col s4">
      </div>
      <div class="col s2 right">
        <a href="" id="signup-button"> Sign Up </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </form>
     </div>
         <div class="col s3">
           </div>
        </div>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login-button").click(function(){
        $("#login").show();
        $("#signup").hide();
   $("#forgetpassword").hide();
  });
 $("#signup-button").click(function(){
   $("#login").hide();
   $("#signup").show();
   $("#forgetpassword").hide();
  });
  $("#forgetpassword-button").click(function(){
   $("#login").hide();
   $("#signup").hide();
    $("#forgetpassword").show();
  });
  });
 </script>
    </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: actuly when ever i click on forget password or sign up in a login div then it shows that forget pass div for 1 sec and then again showing login div

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `e.preventDefault();` to prevent the default behavior of clicking on a link. Your JS code should be like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login-button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#login").show();
        $("#signup").hide();
        $("#forgetpassword").hide();
    });
    $("#signup-button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#login").hide();
        $("#signup").show();
        $("#forgetpassword").hide();
    });
    $("#forgetpassword-button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#login").hide();
        $("#signup").hide();
        $("#forgetpassword").show();
    });
});
```

**Edit:**
`id` can only be used once in an html page, use `class` instead of `id` for your elements and update your JS code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".login-button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#signup").hide();
        $("#forgetpassword").hide();
        $("#login").show();
    });
    $(".signup-button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#login").hide();
        $("#forgetpassword").hide();
        $("#signup").show();
    });
    $(".forgetpassword-button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#login").hide();
        $("#signup").hide();
        $("#forgetpassword").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you now i am getting answer but still some issue that if i am on forgetpassword div and click on login sign up button then its show the login div not sign up div, vice versa  with in sign up div if i click on forget password then it show the login div . @ettanany

Comment: Just edited my answer, please use `class` instead of `id` in your html code, as example use `class="login-button"` instead of `id="login-button"`